# How parse json with unique identifiers into tabular format?

Tags: json, mongodb, jsonparser

Here is a json file I am trying to parse. I have a bunch of such files in a folder and I need to parse them into tabular format.

```
    {
  "block-v1:SampleData-type@chapter+block@14a0423ddf4a4d90926fb348e86a6232": {
    "category": "chapter", 
    "children": [
      "block-v1:SampleData-type@sequential+block@0fd2ac771bd141f384b8a3c628207d1d", 
      //similar sequential blocks
    ], 
    "metadata": {
      "display_name": "XYZZ", 
      "start": "2017-02-13T07:00:00Z"
    }
  }, 
  "block-v1:SampleData-type@chapter+block@46a4c70e4ce94fa5b99b15138d656291": {
    "category": "chapter", 
    "children": [
      "block-v1:SampleData-type@sequential+block@98d28f78d0524360bd51ae57db438c0b"
    ], 
    "metadata": {
      "display_name": "QAQA", 
      "visible_to_staff_only": true
    }
  },
  "block-v1:SampleData-type@discussion+block@3214a8c65ced4efdaaff047ca4854111": {
    "category": "discussion", 
    "children": [], 
    "metadata": {
      "discussion_id": "3fb8fc6eb4f742e7567e8e488789d3132270c4f0", 
      "discussion_target": "MMMMM", 
      "display_name": "MMMMM"
    }
  }
  //similar more category blocks
  // start of all sequential blocks
  "block-v1:SampleData-type@sequential+block@0fd2ac771bd141f384b8a3c628207d1d": {
    "category": "sequential", 
    "children": [
      "block-v1:SampleData-type@vertical+block@aba5c5f4ea104d91bb74f6ce8504fb9d", 
      "block-v1:SampleData-type@vertical+block@973374916a1b4960bb04125906be5350"
    ], 
    "metadata": {
      "display_name": "XYZZ--QQQQ"
    }
  }, 
  // end of all sequential blocks
  // start of all vertical blocks
  "block-v1:SampleData-type@vertical+block@aba5c5f4ea104d91bb74f6ce8504fb9d": {
    "category": "vertical", 
    "children": [
      "block-v1:SampleData-type@video+block@f03bafe28e124a41bb6d86f921ec9d76"
    ], 
    "metadata": {
      "display_name": "XYZZ--QQQQ--AAAA"
    }
  }, 
  "block-v1:SampleData-type@vertical+block@973374916a1b4960bb04125906be5350": {
    "category": "vertical", 
    "children": [
      "block-v1:SampleData-type@html+block@4730907c48e947d1847be66944bbd30d"
    ], 
    "metadata": {
      "display_name": "XYZZ--QQQQ--BBBB"
    }
  }, 
  //end of all vertical blocks
  //
  //
  //
  //similar sequential and vertical blocks for other chapters
  //REMOVE COMMENTS WHILE TRYING TO PARSE THIS DATA
  //
  //
  }
```

Need to get following output:

[output in tabular format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVNpQ.png)

My question is, what is this data with unique identifier called? And, are there any off the shelf tools to parse this data into tabular format?
Or suggestions to create custom parser for this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are there any off the shelf tools to parse this data into tabular format?

Yes: jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Thank you peak for your response. Could you give some sample commands to parse using the tool

Comment: The relationship between your input data and the A/B/C/D/E table is unclear at best.  I would suggest you give an actual example of JSON input and the expected output (perhaps in CSV or TSV format), with a detailed explanation of the relationship between them.  There is probably no "silver bullet" here, but for starters, you might like to try this jq invocation: jq -r '.[] | [.metadata.display_name] | @tsv'.  For further details about jq, please see the tutorial and manual accessible from the link previously given.